# Thunderbird: mails not displayed while everything worked a few minutes ago

Tags: thunderbird

I upgraded my Kaspersky and I closed everything before launching the upgrade process. Everything went well, but when I launched my Thunderbird, no mail and content were displayed.

Everything is blank. Strangely my accounts are detected when expanding Tools/Account Settings.

I completely closed Kaspersky and launched Thunderbird again, but it fixed nothing :(

It is as if closing Thunderbird has damaged a core file. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say for you to go to C:\Users\"Username"\AppData\Roaming\

There should be a Thunderbird Directory or it may even be under a directory "Mozilla"

Backup the profile folder and then remove it. Open Thunderbird again and re-create an email account to see if it works.

If it does then I would say that your Profile had been corrupted due to Kaspersky doing something.

Sorry if this answer was a little confusing.